# Is there an easy/right way to join these vertices?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image: screenshot of the model i'm working on]
I'm making a hexagon-type shape here by first outlining the edges and then proceeding to the centre as mentioned in some tutorial I followed. Is there an efficient/right way to go about this without making a mess of the topology? Links to any relevant tutorials are appreciated too!

Comment: if it doesn't create any artifact you don't need to join the vertices, you can keep a ngon, if that's the question

Comment: @moonboots It didn't create any artifacts yet. I've heard ngons are to be avoided at any cost so I wanted to join the vertices up. Thanks for correcting me!
But what about some models that shouldn't have any ngons? How should I approach fixing the topology there?

Comment: what do you mean by fixing the topology? Again, if you're talking about the fact that you have a ngon, you don't have to care as long as it doesn't creata any artifact

Comment: Hello :). If you don't want the n-gon there, remove it, and use the [Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html#:~:text=Grid%20Fill%20uses%20a%20pair,an%20equal%20number%20of%20vertices) function. It will create quad grid to fill the hole.

Comment: @moonboots By that, I meant if an object has an ngon and it does create artifacts, what would be the steps required to {connect the vertices to create quads/fix the topology} which would in-turn fix the artifact? I am referring to the practice which is shown here in a tutorial. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvJkGEn4UpQ&t=1741s]

Comment: @jachymMichal Hi! Unfortunately, grid fill didn't work in that example above since it dint have the edge loops.

Comment: you have a lot of ways to reduce the amount of vertices, take a look at this site: https://topologyguides.com/ for example the part called Optimal Edge Loop Reduction Flows

Comment: Thank you! This helps a ton!

Comment: The Grid Fill's error message is a bit unclear. You can use Grid Fill on one loop, but it needs even vert count. So most of the cases it helps if you subdivide one of the edges or dissolve a loop.